# How to fix the 'Expected number' error in parallel plot's path attribute in D3.js with CSV input?

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, plot

[d3.js parallel plot] Error:  attribute d: Expected number, "M0,NaNL122.5,NaNL24…".

I tried to visualize a parallel plot with d3.js, exploiting this example with the iris dataset:

https://d3-graph-gallery.com/graph/parallel_custom.html

My csv file is structured as follows:

```
City,GreenAreaDensity,LowEmission,AutobusStopDensity,CirculatingVehicles,ExposedNoisePollution
Torino,7.46,17.3,24.4,277.0,14.9
Vercelli,1.28,11.2,2.1,77.0,8.8
Novara,1.22,11.9,3.8,246.0,14.7
Biella,33.56,10.1,4.1,189.0,9.3
Cuneo,6.82,10.4,6.3,85.0,3.6
Asti,17.14,11.0,1.9,139.0,36.5
Aosta,0.42,8.3,19.0,42.0,6.0
Imperia,1.11,5.4,8.2,191.0,16.7
Savona,7.82,7.7,6.1,183.0,5.1
[...]
```

I get this error in the console for every row in the dataset:

```
Error: <path> attribute d: Expected number, "M0,NaNL122.5,NaNL24…".
```

Which made me think there is a problem in the y coordinates of the path function, so I added various print function to see why there is NaN as the second coordinate.

here the parallelplot.js file:

```
// set the dimensions and margins of the graph
var margin = {top: 30, right: 30, bottom: 10, left: 40},
  width = 560 - margin.left - margin.right,
  height = 400 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

// append the svg object to the body of the page
var svgParallel = d3.select("#parallelPlot")
.append("svg")
  .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
  .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
.append("g")
  .attr("transform",
        "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

// Parse the Data
d3.csv("../../data/processed/ParallelPlotData.csv", function(data) {

  // Here I set the list of dimension manually to control the order of axis:
  dimensions = ["GreenAreaDensity","LowEmission","AutobusStopDensity","CirculatingVehicles","ExposedNoisePollution"]

  // For each dimension, I build a linear scale. I store all in a y object
  var y = {}
  var name;
  for (i in dimensions) {
    name = dimensions[i]
    //console.log(name);
    y[name] = d3.scaleLinear()
    // .domain( [0,150] ) // --> Same axis range for each group
     .domain( [d3.extent(data, function(d) { 
        //console.log(+d[name] + " is of type: " + typeof(+d[name])) // print the value and the type
           return +d[name];   // --> Different axis range for each group
      })] )
      .range([height, 0])
  }

  // Build the X scale -> it find the best position for each Y axis
  x = d3.scalePoint()
    .range([0, width])
    .domain(dimensions);

  // The path function take a row of the csv as input, and return x and y coordinates of the line to draw for this raw.
  function path(d) {
    return d3.line()(dimensions.map(function(column) {
      console.log(y[column](d[column]));
       return [x(column), y[column](d[column])]; 
      })); 
  }

  // Draw the lines
  svgParallel
    .selectAll("myPath")
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append("path")
      .attr("d",  path)
      .style("fill", "none" )
      .style("stroke", function(){ return("#AAA")} )
      .style("opacity", 0.5)
 
  // Draw the axis:
  svgParallel.selectAll("myAxis")
    // For each dimension of the dataset I add a 'g' element:
    .data(dimensions).enter()
    .append("g")
    .attr("class", "axis")
    // I translate this element to its right position on the x axis
    .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + x(d) + ")"; })
    // And I build the axis with the call function
    .each(function(d) { d3.select(this).call(d3.axisLeft().ticks(5).scale(y[d])); })
    // Add axis title
    .append("text")
      .style("text-anchor", "middle")
      .attr("y", -9)
      .text(function(d) { return d; })
      .style("fill", "black")

})
```

In fact the value ycolumn returns NaN, but here if I print d[column] returns the exact value I want on that axis.

This problem is irrelevant if I choose fixed axis for every parameter, but I need different range for the axis:

```
// For each dimension, I build a linear scale. I store all in a y object
  var y = {}
  var name;
  for (i in dimensions) {
    name = dimensions[i]
    //console.log(name);
    y[name] = d3.scaleLinear()
    // .domain( [0,150] ) // --> Same axis range for each group
      .domain( [d3.extent(data, function(d) { 
        //console.log(+d[name] + " is of type: " + typeof(+d[name])) // print the value and the type
           return +d[name];   // --> Different axis range for each group
      })] )
      .range([height, 0])
  }
```

The problem may also lay here since apparently it doesn't read the correct coordinate value so there is no path in visualization.

The parallel plot is like this:
[image]

It is possible to see that the range value for each feature must be different since there are various metrics.

Someone can help me figure out how to solve this?

Comment: What is 'Parallel plot'? Can you post a picture to illustrate it?

Comment: what is the function `x()`? what is `dimensions`? Please share the full code or a simplified version

Comment: Just added a graphical reference of the plot

Comment: I think that x() is a method of d3.line that returns the value of the x-axis in the graph (in fact the error correctly takes the value of the x-axis in correspondence with the first vertical axis of the GreenAreaDensity [x=0] and subsequently of the second vertical axis of the LowEmissions [x=122.5] and so on)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your bug lies on the `d3.extent()` call. This function itself returns an array, so you should pass that directly to `d3.scaleLinear().domain(...)`.
Here is the fixed code:

```
  var y = {}
  var name;
  for (i in dimensions) {
    name = dimensions[i]
    y[name] = d3.scaleLinear()
      .domain(
        d3.extent(data, function (d) {  // Note d3.extent result is used as is
          return +d[name];
        })
      )
      .range([height, 0])
  }
```

[Working StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so76371176?file=index.js)